# Retrieve value from the selected index in Tree Model

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a container class which is the datatype in the treeItem class.

My tree structure works fine but how do i retrive the value of the Container data type from the selected item.

This is how i have defined my functions for data.

As far as my understaning from the tree view example of QT we return the data in Data function which cannot be a object but should be concrete value.

```
class Container
 {
   private:
   std::string stdstrContainerName;
   std::string stdstrPluginType;   
 public:
    Container();
    Container(std::string , std::string ,  int , float);
    Container(const  Container& obj);  
    ~Container();
    std::string GetName();
    std::string GetType();
     void SetName(std::string stdstrName);
  };
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Container )

class TreeItem
 {
   public:       
       /* Other Functions of the class 
        */
       Container data() const;
       bool setData(const Container &data);

   private:
        QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
         Container itemData;
      TreeItem* parentItem;
  };


 QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
   {
     if (!index.isValid())
       return QVariant();

       if (role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::EditRole)
         return QVariant();

        TreeItem *item = getItem(index);

       // i wanted to return data from here.

        return QString::fromStdString(item->data().GetName());  // if i 

        //return Container as datatype or return Container as QVariant  than 
        //the tree structure does not work.
       // It only works if i have a concrete value rather that a object.
   }

  // data function of TreeItem
  Container TreeItem::data() const
  {
     return itemData; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new function in TreeModel.

```
Container TreeModel::GetContainer(const QModelIndex &index)
 {
    TreeItem *item = getItem(index);
    return (item->data());
 }
```

Than casted the AbstractModel to the TreeModel.

```
 void SumTreeProject::PrintData()
 {
    QModelIndex index = treeView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    QAbstractItemModel *model = treeView->model();
    TreeModel *myModel = qobject_cast<TreeModel*>( model);
    Container cont =  myModel->GetContainer(index);
    qDebug() << cont.GetType().c_str(); // Able to print the value
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution is one way to do it.

A criticism would be that it tightly couples your view to your model.

On the other hand, any Qt model is relatively tightly coupled to its views, at least regarding the interpretation of the columns, returned data types or the item hierarchy.

Having said this, and regarding that you only need `Container::GetType()` data, another method to do what you want is:

1. Have your model's `data(QModelIndex index, int role)` function return the `Container::GetType()` result for a specific column, let's say `index.column()==1`. (You already described that `index.row()` specifies the desired `Container` instance.)
2. Your `SumTreeProject::PrintData()` method needs to get a `QModelIndex` with the row from `treeView->selectionModel()->currentIndex()` and column 1 by calling `treeView->model()->index(row, 1)`.
3. With this index you get the data from `treeView->model()->data(index).toString()`.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need to include `TreeModel.h` or `Container.h` in your `SumTreeProject` code.